# Bought agency bond (FANNIE MAE 0% 04/08/2027), now what?

Tags: bonds, government-bonds

I just bought 15 of these for $10,677 through my brokerage firm. It says 3.3% interest. I have no idea how this works. But I trust it is gov bond and will pay 3.3%. 
Can anyone explain how it works? Will it pay interest annually or every 6 months?

This is the bond:

> 31364DKK1 - FANNIE MAE 0% 04/08/2027

Comment: Sorry, but I can't help but ask why you would spend over $10k on something if you don't really get how it works? Surely it could have waited  a day until you figure out how bonds work?

Comment: Begin by reading this, *all of it*, as you probably should have done before you spent the money. http://www.fanniemae.com/resources/file/debt/pdf/debt_library.pdf

Comment: Is that actually just "over $10k", or is it actually **15 times** "over $10k"? Even more frightening if it is actually $160k.

Comment: @shoover Bonds typically trade at $1000 face value (par value), i.e. what one is due to receive at maturity, so the $10,677 is the discounted price (present value) of the $15,000 (15  x $1000) to be received at maturity.

Comment: @ChrisW.Rea Ah, ok, that's why I'm here, for learning. But I'd rather learn **first**, before dumping the money into it like OP. ;-)

Comment: This isn't really an answer to this question per se, but just as some advice for the future: 3.3% annualized over 10.5 years is a pretty terrible rate of return, especially when it's not an extremely rock-solid investment. When you take inflation from now through 2027 into account, you'd be lucky to break even on this. There are a few situations were such an investment could make sense (i.e. when the goal is only prevention of loss of capital and not growth of capital,) but it doesn't make much sense in most cases.

Comment: Thank you all for the responses. I placed the order and posted the question. The final price paid was $10,649. It is compounding at a rate of 3.335% as calculated by `$10649*(1.0335)**10.4=$15,001` (this is 10.4-year bond).  Without compounding, I would have only got `10649+10649 *.0335*10.4=$14,359`. The difference is $600. This is nice because if it were to pay me interest every year, I would not be able to re-invest the interest money easily  to perform the compounding.

Answer (score 124, accepted):

Neither. What you appear to have purchased is a zero coupon bond. In under 10 1/2 years,  your $10,677 will grow to $15,000. This is a compound 3.3% per year. To be clear, the return comes from the fact that you paid less than the $15000 face value that you will get at maturity, only you do not receive interest along the way.

By the way, no offense intended, but I'm a bit frightened to read," I have no idea how this works", and "I just spent $10,000" in the same sentence.  Nothing wrong with the purchase itself, but in the future please do the research first so you know the mechanics of what you're purchasing.

Comment: Thanks. I really thought this could not go wrong  because the bond is a Gov bond. It is very interesting to know that the bond compounding by itself and I do not have to re-invest the interests every 6 month or 1 year.

Comment: @Tony It doesn't really compound at all, as there is no interest. If you invested $10,677 in a compounding product with 3.3% annual interest, that product would also be worth $15k in 2027, so the bond behaves like having 3.3% interest per year.

Comment: Is this actually a government bond?  I though fanne Mae was a government sponsored enterprise which whilst has received public support during the crisis years will at some point be returned to the private sector.

Comment: @SMeaden: It is not. It took me less than 30 seconds to find "Fannie Mae’s debt securities are unsecured obligations of the corporation only and are not backed by the full faith and credit of the U.S. Government." on their web site. Which is work that the original poster perhaps ought to have done before spending the cash.

Comment: @CodesInChaos - but, from a mathematical view, it does compound. If you take the stated 3.3% and work backwards, you find that you need to apply a quarterly compounding to get the 15K face value. If the rate remained 100% steady (that will never happen, of course), OP would see his value rise so each year it would tick up a bit over 3.3% from the prior year. Even though FNMA is doing nothing since it's a zero.

Comment: @SMeaden Fannie was only ever tenuously 'private sector' in the first place. It was created by an act of Congress (as part of FDR's 'New Deal' during the Great Depression) and its charter explicitly requires it to further the "affordable housing" goals specified by the Department of Housing and Urban Development (HUD) and approved by Congress. It's a weird mix of public/private where its common stock was publically traded for a few decades, but its goals are largely set by the federal government. That said, its bonds aren't "government bonds" in the sense of being backed by the government.

Comment: @Eric Lippert: From from of your programming blogs : 'Duck typing is so-called because of the principle “if it walks like a duck and quacks like a duck then it is a duck”'   So if a bond is bailed out by the government then it is a government bond, ergo Fannie Mae is a government bond.

Comment: @SMeaden Lots of things look like ducks - until they don't

Comment: @Brad Thomas: Whatever.  My first comment was discussive and then I felt Eric's comment was needlessly dismissive and implied that the point was black and white, I stand by my first comment that with GSEs it is a shade of grey and then government bailout shaded it even closer to sovereign status.  It takes less than 30 seconds to find Ben Bernanke endorsing the bailout https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Federal_takeover_of_Fannie_Mae_and_Freddie_Mac and thus de facto Fannie Mae is 'backed by the full faith and credit of the U.S. Government'.  Anyway, as a Brit, perhaps I should step out of US talk.

Answer (score 41):

Since it sounds like you are just starting out in bonds, let me first tell you a little about how bonds work before moving on to answering your actual question.

Whereas stocks represent a portion of ownership of a company, a bond (somewhat simplified) represents a portion of a company or state *loan*. Effectively, **when you buy the bond, you are extending a loan to the entity that issued the bond.**

Like stocks, bonds are traded in the public market. Like stocks, bonds can rise and fall in price as investors change their mind about whoever issued the bond. Like stocks, bonds fall in price when they are less favored by the investor collective, and increase in price when they are more favored.

*Unlike stocks, how much a bond pays is fixed when the bond is issued.* This is known as the "coupon" of the bond, and is often expressed as a percentage of the nominal value of the bond.

The bond also has an end date, known as its *maturity* or maturation date. At that date, whoever issued the bond will pay, to the current holder, the *nominal value* of the bond, and the bond ceases to exist. (They are paying off the loan that is represented by the bond, so the bond no longer has any meaningful reason to exist. Were it not to cease to exist, its value would be set to zero, as the money has been paid.)

A third important piece of information for a bond, alluded to above, is the *nominal value* of the bond. The nominal value of a bond is the amount that will be paid when the bond matures. This, too, is fixed when the bond is issued.

Now, if a bond is disfavored by the investor collective, it will be trading at *below par*. Another way to say the same thing is that its price is depressed, or lower than the nominal value of the bond. (The opposite is *above par*.) *Slight* variation around the nominal value is nothing to be alarmed about, but a bond trading at a price significantly different from its nominal value is a potential red flag.

**One reason for a bond trading significantly below par is that the entity that stands behind the bond (in this case, Fannie Mae), is doing poorly financially.** In such a situation, there is the risk of a *credit event* in the bond. **"Credit events" are, for example, bankruptcy, debt restructuring, debt forgiveness, and so on.** What this means is that if there is a credit event involving the bond, you may not get its full nominal value back at the expected maturity date, either because the nominal value is changed (sometimes down to zero), sometimes because the maturity date is changed (often to a later date), sometimes both.

In this case, **the bond you purchased has a 0% coupon rate. In other words, it pays no regular *interest.*** Any return on investment must therefore come only from the difference between purchase value and final value, and considering the time to maturity. Investors like to get a return on their investments, so it is expected to see the current value of the bond to be lower than the nominal value.

**You bought the bond for $10,677, while as JoeTaxpayer pointed out, the nominal value is $15,000 to be paid in April 2027.** 3.3% per year for 10.5 years corresponds to about 40.6% over those years, and just so it happens, 1.406 * $10,677 = $15,014, working out almost exactly to the difference between its current value and its nominal value. (I very much suspect that a more accurate calculation would yield a result even closer to the nominal value of $15,000.) **As you can thus see, the "3.3% interest" is really a 3.3% *annual return*.** Calling it "interest" is likely a simplification to make it more understandable.

**The above calculation assumes that you keep the bond to maturity, and that no credit event occurs which involves the bond you purchased.** If either of those conditions do not fully hold, then the outcome (in this case) depends solely on the difference between the price you paid for the bond and the price you sell it for, as well as any applicable tax effects.

As [Eric Lippert](https://money.stackexchange.com/users/6122/eric-lippert) has already pointed out in the comments to JoeTaxpayer's answer, Fannie Mae bonds are corporate bonds *not* backed by "the full faith and credit of the U.S. government".

Also, even government bonds come with a certain amount of risk. For a recent example, consider the [2011 Greece government debt restructuring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greek_government-debt_crisis#2011) where

> Private bondholders were required to accept extended maturities, lower interest rates and a 53.5% reduction in the bonds' face value.

Greece, of course, is just one example. There are several more where large countries have needed various forms of debt restructuring in the last few decades alone.

**So don't assume that even a bond that is backed by your government is a "safe" investment. History shows that it will be, until it isn't any longer.**

Bottom line: *Diversification remains your friend.*

Comment: Nicely done. Your writing never disappoints.

Comment: I've taken the gamble once or twice of buying bonds that were trading at something like 45% below par while paying a reasonably substantial coupon. That said, I did so knowing perfectly well that it was a gamble. Those particular ones have worked out well so far... the particular ones I have now mature around 2019/2020, so it'll be interesting to see if they hold up over the coming three years.

Comment: Might be worth fleshing out the "if you sell it" portion - given theoretically the price should increase slowly over time (roughly 3.3% per year, plus/minus risk changes, in theory?) so he may be able to / want to exit earlier than 2027 and still have some gains.

Comment: +1, though I'd say that, as others have pointed out, the bottom line should read: *Knowing what you are doing is your friend.*

Answer (score 12):

I would like to point out one issue that has not been discussed in either JoeTaxpayer's answer or Michael Kjörling's answer.

> While a "zero-coupon" bond pays no interest each year/quarter/month (in the sense of sending cash to the investor that the investor can put in
>   the bank or spend -- because there no coupons to
>   redeem), *in general*, the interest that supposedly *accrues* 
>   each year is
>   *taxable income* to the investor for that year, unless of course the bond is being held in a tax-deferred account.  In particular, taxes on the interest cannot be deferred until the bond is cashed in upon maturity
>   as they can with Series EE US Savings Bonds,* the zero-coupon bond
>   that most people are familiar with. For this reason, most investors prefer to *not* hold zero-coupon bonds in taxable portfolios.

*It didn't used to be a good idea to defer interest income on EE bonds
for children but instead to declare the interest each year and pay the
tax on it on behalf of the child at the child's rate. That way, when
the bond was cashed in, tax would be due only on interest accrued in
the last year. The more recent tax law changes re children's income
being taxed not at the kiddie rate but at the parents' rate may have
changed all this.

Comment: So are you saying on OP's purchase he will have to pay income taxes rather than capital gains?

Comment: @BradThomas With a bond, there are **no capital gains** except in the unlikely event that the bond is sold to someone else for more than its purchase price _plus_ imputed interest up to the date of sale. In the year of sale, imputed interest for that year will be taxed as interest, the _excess_ as capital gains. If the bond is redeemed by returning it FannieMae on the date of maturity and getting cash back, then income tax is due on the imputed interest earned in the year of sale. Income tax on imputed interest during previous years will have been paid with the tax returns of previous years.